# Run timed PHP function via SQL

Tags: php, sql, execute

Is there a way to run a PHP file automatically every hour?
Via SQL or some other way. 
I'm currently working on a file who's job is to bring information from a table every hour. 
This file needs to execute every hour.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you use cron on your host?

Comment: Check *crontab* if your using linux/unix.

Comment: Please provide additional info such as your OS and whether or not you are paying for a hosting service or have your own server.

Comment: If you dont have a crontab you could use a service to execute your file on-time: http://www.mywebcron.com. The other option is what they call a "Poor Mans Cron" which is not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Neither PHP nor MySQL has this ability.

This function is normally available either by your operating system or external tool.

Windows has a job scheduler, or Unix and variants has crontab, where you can specify a command that must be run on a periodic basis.

Comment: Not true, MySQL has "events".

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks for the clarification. I will delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is not a build-in facility. however it can be done by some external tools or using some other php code written for it and loaded on the machine

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Do you have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have cron on your host, you can use it. Cron runs php script or any other script every time you want to. It's automated so you just put time details in to it and let it do it's magics itself.

First, put your script that you want to run every hour into file. Then search cron, or crontab from your cpanel(or what are you using). Then set time details(if you have those inputs on your cpanel). Then, write to command input: `php /your/full/path/here/`. If you don't have GUI for setting crons(cron times), you can use this command:

```
0 * * * * php /your/full/path/here/
```

Answer (score 0):

Cronjobs has been mentioned in the questions above me. And you should try to find a solution with cronjobs.

But if you can't, you can use the php time_sleep_until function.
The doc is here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time-sleep-until.php

You input a timestamp in the first parameter, and the php script will sleep until given time.
And then you just while it forever. Not a good solution, but it works.

Remember to ignore user abort and set timeout to infinite.